# Exchange 2007: Public folder moved to public addressbook

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders

One of our clients accidently moved a public folder into a public addressbook. Sadly, it's not possible to move that folder back and there is no database-level backup of the exchange (a new message is opening when we try to drag and drop the folder back to its old place).

The exchange server is a small business server 2008 with exchange 2007.

This is how it looks now:
[image]

Any Idea how we can get this public folder back?

no ideas?